# Question on uniform convergence of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $(f_{n})_{n}$ is a sequence of differentiable functions defined on an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $(f'_{n})_{n}$ converges uniformly on $I$ and that there exists an $x_{0} \in I$ for which $(f_{n}(x_{0}))_{n}$ converges. Then $(f_{n}(x))_{n}$ converges for every $x \in I$.

So this means that convergence in one point $x_{0}$ implies pointwise convergence on all of $I$. I'm not sure on how to start proving this. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You can find proof of this theorem in 'Introduction to real analysis' by Bartle and Sherbert. Note that convergence $f_n(x)$ is uniform.

Comment: Is $f_{n}(x)$ not only definitely uniform if $I$ is bounded?

Comment: Yup. $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on a bounded interval of $\Bbb R$.